# Using in-memory filesystem for testing systems software in golang

Tags: linux, unit-testing, go, testing, system

I'd like to create an in-memory filesystem for testing in golang

Contrived Use case:
Although Go has packages to achieve this, I would like to use this as a simple example for what I want to do

```
func GetProcessSessionId(pid int) (int, error) {
    sessionidFile := fmt.Sprintf("/proc/%v/sessionid", pid)
    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile(sessionidFile)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return strconv.Atoi(string(dat))
}
```

Now assume that I have many functions that gather information about processes and want to test them all by having a file system that contains multiple processes in the `/proc` directory. What would be a good way to structure my project to be able to do this?

Is there a good way to leverage the updates in Go 1.16 with the new io/fs package `https://golang.org/pkg/io/fs/` or embedded files?

Am I taking the wrong approach for testing systems level software with golang and should think about approach?

Comment: Do you need to write to the files, or only read?

Comment: ["A MapFS is a simple in-memory file system for use in tests."](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/fstest/#MapFS)

Comment: @HymnsForDisco once the filesystem is set up read-only is fine. I think the part Im trying to figure out is whats the cleanest way to create a /proc filesystem during test setup